# Error building Python extension using boost.python

Tags: c++, python-3.5, boost-python

I installed `boost` as well as `boost-python`, and `boost-build` using `homebrew` on my Mac with OS X 10.11.6. I am running Python 3.5.2. `boost` is set up correctly and works in C++ projects. Both, `user-config.jam` and the jamfile located in my python extension project directory are ok. I tried to compile a shared library from the following source

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

using namespace std;


void say_hello() {
    std::cout << "HELLO!!!!!";
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello) {
    using namespace boost::python;
    def ("say_hello", say_hello);
}
```

using the `b2` interpreter. It issues the following command:

```
"g++" -dynamiclib -Wl,-single_module -install_name "hello.so" -L"/usr/local/lib/python3.5" -o "bin/darwin-4.2.1/release/hello.so" "bin/darwin-4.2.1/release/say_hello.o"  -lpython3.5    -headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-dead_strip -no_dead_strip_inits_and_terms
```

, which crash with

> darwin.link.dll bin/darwin-4.2.1/release/hello.so
>
> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>
> "typeinfo for boost::python::objects::py_function_impl_base", referenced from:
>
> [...long trace back ...]
>
> "boost::python::detail::init_module(PyModuleDef&, void (*)())", referenced from:
>
> _PyInit_hello in say_hello.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

I am very aware of all the question concerning similar problems, but  unfortunately none of them provides a working answer.

What do I have to do I order to get this simple code working as an Python extension module?

Answer (score 0):

You should link it with boost python library as well( as boost.python is not header only). Here is how boost libraries are include in the build command(paths as I have on my machine):

```
-L/usr/lib/libpython2.7.dylib /usr/local/lib/libboost_system-mt.dylib /usr/local/lib/libboost_python-mt.dylib /usr/lib/libpython2.7.dylib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/libpython2.7.dylib
```

I assume you can do without `libboost_system` library. (Such output I get when run `make VERBOSE=1` as I'm not running `make` explicitly.)

Regarding cmake, here is a simple `CMakeLists.txt` you can use to build a project with `Boost.Python`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(LIBRARY_NAME "ext") # ext for extension

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -Wall -ggdb")

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

set(SOURCES
    python_interface.cpp
    main.cpp
)

set(CMAKE_MACOSX_RPATH ON)

# Get Boost
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS
    system
    python REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})

# Get Python
find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})

add_library(${LIBRARY_NAME} SHARED ${SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(${LIBRARY_NAME} 
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
    ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES}
)
```